# VBA Password Prompt shows on Exit from Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have been experiencing an issue where the VBA Password Prompt appears when exiting Excel for workbooks that have a locked VBA project.

[image: VBA Password Prompt]

For me it is happening on a Win10 / Excel2013 and Win10 / Excel2016 environment. I have searched for and tried a number of possible solutions. See the attached workbook and a step recorder that shows this happening for one of the tests. One interesting difference for the tests that are included to the workbook is in the case where a "pop-up" form is displayed, when closing the VBA password prompt is shown 5 times instead of 3 times on a standard exit from the workbook for the other tests.

Sample Workbook - https://sites.google.com/a/xlautomation.com.au/website/free-downloads/TestVBAPassword%20v2%20Share.xlsm?attredirects=0&d=1

Password to see the code in this workbook...."password"

Step Recorder showing the issue - https://sites.google.com/a/xlautomation.com.au/website/free-downloads/VBA%20Password%20Prompt%20Example.zip?attredirects=0&d=1

I can see from other posts that this problem has appeared over the years and some have resolved it with removing Add-In references, Closing Excel in a certain way none of these are working in my case. It is not a viable option to unprotect the VBA project as the workbooks are shared with others and allowing access to the code would present support issues.

If anyone has further suggestions to resolve this issue please share those back.
I have also include a demo of the issue in action below...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could it be you have Dropbox installed on your system. A weird pointer to it solved my solution (short of making the Excel sheet into an xlam add-in) in no longer asking for the password:

1. right click on Dropbox symbol in system tray
2. Select the gear symbol (settings) at the right top
3. Select "Preferences"
4. In its "General"tab set "Show Dropbox Badge" to "Never show".
5. Click OK

That's it. How that affects Excel I don't know.